# como terminar un ciclo for si tiene un else, y después continuarlo con su siguiente iteración

Tags: c++, array, dev-c++

Al momento de ejecutar el código no se como hacer para que al momento de tener un  falso dentro de un ciclo for pase a la siguiente "pasada" y continuar cuando sea verdad como muestra el ejemplo(imágenes), en mi código solo muestra las ultimas iteraciones de cada "pasada " y no muestra como va recorriendo el 9 (como en el ejemplo) además de  queda en la primera pasada ,  así es mi código.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
int mm=7,dato[20]={25,10,38,62,9,29,50},i,pu=0,r,j,v,k,pos,aux,m;

        
        cout<<"***Arreglo original***\n";
        for(k=0;k<mm;k++)
        cout<<dato[k]<<" ";
        cout<<"\n";    
        for(k=1;k<mm-1;k++){ 
         cout<<"Pasada"<<k<<"\n";    
       for(i=1;i<mm;i++){
        cout<<dato[i]<<" < "<<dato[i-1];
        if(dato[i]<dato[i-1]){
        cout<<" v ";
        
        aux=dato[i];
        j=i-1;
    
        while(j>=0&&dato[j]>aux){   
            dato[j+1]=dato[j];
            j--;
        
            
           } 
           dato[j+1]=aux;
             for(k=0;k<mm;k++)
        {
            cout<<"\t";
            cout<<dato[k];
         } 
       cout<<"\n";
       
     
       }
       else{
        cout<<" f ";
        for(k=0;k<mm;k++)
        {
            cout<<"\t";
            cout<<dato[k];
         } 
           cout<<"\n";
       }
       
       }

       
}
        for(k=0;k<mm;k++)
        {
            cout<<"\t";
            cout<<dato[k]<<endl;
         } 
         }
```

[image: Ejemplo de como debe aparecer la ejecución]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una instruccion llamada continue que en el caso de que sea false pase a la siguiente iteracion del bucle for ,un ejemplo

```
for (int i=0;i<10;++i){

if(m[i]==2){

 //otra instruccion

}else{


  continue;

}


}
```

Comment: Cuando escribes una respuesta, quien pregunta recibe automáticamente una notificación. No se le puede referenciar en las respuestas ya que esas referencias no van a ninguna parte

Answer (score 0):

No llegue a comprender lo que deseas hacer del todo, pero segun entendi es que quieres que el ciclo for termine cuando una condicion no se cumple verdad, pues para eso puedes hacer:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    cin>>a;
    if(a<100){
        cout<<"introduce otro valor"<<endl;
    }else i=10+1;
}
```

como puedes ver en el codigo la manera de detener un ciclo for es haciendo que el contador que en caso del ejemplo era "i" cumpla la condicion y se detenga el ciclo.

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales en tu respuesta. Tal como está escrita actualmente, es difícil entender tu solución.

Comment: Para eso existe el `break`. Mucho más claro y limpio.